# iphone opengl es 2.0, how to use objective-c class to store primitive data?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am trying to use nsarray of objective-c class called Primitive which stores primitive data such as vertices, texture coordinates, vertexBuffer, indexBuffer and texture buffer.

But it is not drawing the rectangle with texture. 
When I tried c struct that contains same info, it drew fine.

I am not sure where I am missing
Can anyone give me some hint?

```
//Here is my primitive class. 
//It also has Vertex class which has vertex positions and texture coordinates
// This represents one primitive, in this app, it is rectangle
@interface Primitive : NSObject
{
    @public
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    GLuint indexBuffer;
    GLuint textureBuffer;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * vertices; //consist 4 vertices

- (id)initWithVertices:(NSArray *)vertices;

@end


@interface Vertex : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * position; //(x,y,z) per vertex
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * textureCoordinate; //(s,t) per vertex

- (id)initWithPointX:(float)x Y:(float)y Z:(float)z;
- (void)printVal;
@end



@implementation Primitive

@synthesize vertices = m_vertices;

- (id)initWithVertices:(NSArray *)vertices
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        m_vertices = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:vertices];
    }

    return self;
}

@end

@implementation Vertex

@synthesize position = m_position;
@synthesize textureCoordinate = m_textureCoordinate;

- (id)initWithPointX:(float)x Y:(float)y Z:(float)z
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        m_position = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x], 
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:y], 
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:z], nil];
    }

    return self;
}


// and here is how I generate vbo. it's in other file
- (void)setupVertexBufferObjects
{

    for(Primitive * primitive in m_primitives)
    {
        NSLog(@"setting vbo");

        glGenBuffers(1,  &primitive->vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, primitive->vertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(primitive.vertices), 
                     (__bridge void *)primitive.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &primitive->indexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, primitive->indexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
}

// and this is how I render, this is also in other file than Primitive and above method
// this one worked fine when I had c struct to provide vertices and texture coordinate
glClearColor(0, 104.0/255, 55.0/255, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLuint positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(m_programHandle, "Position");


glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);


glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                      [m_candleModel sizeOfVertex], 0);



GLuint texCoordSlot = glGetAttribLocation(m_programHandle, "TexCoordIn");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordSlot);
GLuint textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(m_programHandle, "Texutre");


glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                      [m_candleModel sizeOfVertex], (GLvoid *)(sizeof(float) * 3));

GLuint floorTexture = [m_candleModel getTexture];

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);


glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);


[m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to make a rigid object that won't change shape I would recommend taking info like position, scale, rotation, etc. and then changing the vertices to fit the info. Here's a class I'm currently working on that makes a black square which can do rotation, opacity, position, and size. Hope it helps

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
} Vertex;

@interface GameSprite : NSObject
{
    GLuint positionAttrib;
    GLuint colorAttrib;

    GLuint programHandle;
    GLuint modelviewUniform;

    CGSize spriteSize;

    CGPoint position;
    float rotation;
    float alpha;

    BOOL HasRotated;
}

-(id) init;
-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size AndPosition:(CGPoint)spritePosition;

-(void) render;

-(void) setPosition:(CGPoint)newPosition;
-(void) setRotation:(float)newRotation;
-(void) setAlpha:(float)newAlpha;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) CGPoint getPosition;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) float getRotation;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) float getAlpha;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) CGSize getSize;

@end
```

Implementation...

```
#define kPI180   0.017453
#define k180PI  57.295780
#define degreesToRadians(x) (x * kPI180)
#define radiansToDegrees(x) (x * k180PI)

const Vertex GameSpriteVertices[] = {
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}},
    {{1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}},
    {{2, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}},
    {{2, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
};

const GLubyte GameSpriteIndices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 1
};

@implementation GameSprite
@synthesize getPosition, getRotation, getAlpha, getSize;

-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size AndPosition:(CGPoint)spritePosition
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        position = spritePosition;
        getPosition = position;
        rotation = 0;
        getRotation = rotation;
        alpha = 1.0;
        getAlpha = alpha;

        spriteSize = size;
        getSize = spriteSize;

        GLuint VertexShader = [self compileShader:@"VertexShader" withType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
        GLuint FragmentShader = [self compileShader:@"FragmentShader" withType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

        programHandle = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(programHandle, VertexShader);
        glAttachShader(programHandle, FragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(programHandle);

        glUseProgram(programHandle);

        positionAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position");
        colorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "SourceColor");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttrib);

        modelviewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Modelview");
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        GLuint VertexShader = [self compileShader:@"VertexShader" withType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
        GLuint FragmentShader = [self compileShader:@"FragmentShader" withType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

        programHandle = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(programHandle, VertexShader);
        glAttachShader(programHandle, FragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(programHandle);

        glUseProgram(programHandle);

        positionAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position");
        colorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "SourceColor");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttrib);

        GLuint vertexBuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GameSpriteVertices), GameSpriteVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLuint indexBuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GameSpriteIndices), GameSpriteIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        modelviewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Modelview");

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) render
{
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Add the position to the square
    Vertex TempVertices[] = {
        {{position.x - spriteSize.width/2, position.y - spriteSize.height/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, alpha}},
        {{position.x - spriteSize.width/2, position.y + spriteSize.height/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, alpha}},
        {{position.x + spriteSize.width/2, position.y - spriteSize.height/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, alpha}},
        {{position.x + spriteSize.width/2, position.y + spriteSize.height/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, alpha}}
    };

    // Add the rotation to the square
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(TempVertices)/sizeof(TempVertices[0]); i++) { 
        CGPoint vertex = CGPointMake(TempVertices[i].Position[0], TempVertices[i].Position[1]);
        TempVertices[i].Position[0] = [self rotatePoint:vertex by:rotation around:position].x;
        TempVertices[i].Position[1] = [self rotatePoint:vertex by:rotation around:position].y;
    }

    const GLubyte TempIndices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 1
    };

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TempVertices), TempVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint indexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TempIndices), TempIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttrib, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(GameSpriteIndices)/sizeof(GameSpriteIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}

/*
 Porgrammer access methods
 */

-(void) setPosition:(CGPoint)newPosition
{
    position = newPosition;
    getPosition = position;
}

-(void) setRotation:(float)newRotation 
{
    rotation = newRotation;
    getRotation = rotation;
}

-(void) setAlpha:(float)newAlpha
{
    alpha = newAlpha;
    getAlpha = alpha;
}


/*
 Helper methods
 */
-(GLuint) compileShader:(NSString *)path withType:(GLenum)shaderType 
{
    NSString *shaderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"glsl"];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *shaderString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:shaderPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const char * shaderStringUTF8 = [shaderString UTF8String];    
    int shaderStringLength = [shaderString length];
    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &shaderStringUTF8, &shaderStringLength);

    glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

    return shaderHandle;
}

-(CGPoint) rotatePoint:(CGPoint)point by:(float)theta around:(CGPoint)origin
{
    theta = degreesToRadians(theta);
    CGPoint newPoint;

    newPoint.x = cosf(theta) * (point.x - origin.x) - sinf(theta) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x;
    newPoint.y = sinf(theta) * (point.x - origin.x) + cosf(theta) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y;

    return newPoint;
}

@end
```